# Convert List Column to String of Comma-Separated Values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following `data.frame`.  How can I convert the `color_names` column to a comma-separated string?  A `dplyr` solution is preferable.

```r
tibble::tibble(
  col_hex = c("#0087BF", "#FF0000"),
  col_freq = c(87462L, 87019L),
  col_share = c(0.501269479198308, 0.498730520801692),
  color_names = list('deepskyblue3', c("red", "red1"))
)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   col_hex col_freq col_share color_names
#>   <chr>      <int>     <dbl> <list>     
#> 1 #0087BF    87462     0.501 <chr [1]>  
#> 2 #FF0000    87019     0.499 <chr [2]>
```

My desired output is below.

```r
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   col_hex col_freq col_share color_names 
#>   <chr>      <int>     <dbl> <chr>       
#> 1 #0087BF    87462     0.501 deepskyblue3
#> 2 #FF0000    87019     0.499 red, red1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

    tibble::tibble(
    col_hex = c("#0087BF", "#FF0000"),
    col_freq = c(87462L, 87019L),
    col_share = c(0.501269479198308, 0.498730520801692),
    color_names = list('deepskyblue3', c("red", "red1"))
    ) %>% 
    mutate(color_names = map_chr(color_names, ~str_c(.x, collapse = ", ")))
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `dplyr`, you can use `toString` and `mutate` by row:

```
x %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(color_names = toString(color_names))

# col_hex   col_freq col_share color_names 
# <chr>        <int>     <dbl> <chr>       
# 1 #0087BF    87462     0.501 deepskyblue3
# 2 #FF0000    87019     0.499 red, red1
```

If speed is of concern, the answer from @Friede seems *substantially faster*.

When expanded to 20,000 rows:

```
bigx <- x[rep(1:2, 1e4),]

#Unit: milliseconds
#      expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      #max neval  cld
#   jpsmith 141.68251 159.14643 172.13023 170.68616 183.51536 232.3752   100 a   
#     marco 503.84060 542.87272 572.25619 559.12097 589.89215 819.0019   100  b  
# joshbrows 329.12367 353.49528 377.68140 367.49608 388.77929 729.1720   100   c 
#    friede  72.47281  81.17153  91.67497  84.13152  94.80134 487.1501   100    d
```

Data

```
x <- tibble::tibble(
  col_hex = c("#0087BF", "#FF0000"),
  col_freq = c(87462L, 87019L),
  col_share = c(0.501269479198308, 0.498730520801692),
  color_names = list('deepskyblue3', c("red", "red1"))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on Marco's answer, I found a succinct solution.

```r
library(tidyverse)

tibble(
  col_hex = c("#0087BF", "#FF0000"),
  col_freq = c(87462L, 87019L),
  col_share = c(0.501269479198308, 0.498730520801692),
  color_names = list('deepskyblue3', c("red", "red1"))
) %>% 
  mutate(
    col_chr = map_chr(color_names, str_flatten_comma)
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   col_hex col_freq col_share color_names col_chr     
#>   <chr>      <int>     <dbl> <list>      <chr>       
#> 1 #0087BF    87462     0.501 <chr [1]>   deepskyblue3
#> 2 #FF0000    87019     0.499 <chr [2]>   red, red1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

An R approach using `base`.

```r
is.data.frame(clr)
#> [1] TRUE
clr$color_names <- vapply(clr$color_names, toString, character(1L))
clr
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   col_hex col_freq col_share color_names 
#>   <chr>      <int>     <dbl> <chr>       
#> 1 #0087BF    87462     0.501 deepskyblue3
#> 2 #FF0000    87019     0.499 red, red1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

**Data**

```r
clr <- tibble::tibble(
  col_hex = c("#0087BF", "#FF0000"),
  col_freq = c(87462L, 87019L),
  col_share = c(0.501269479198308, 0.498730520801692),
  color_names = list('deepskyblue3', c("red", "red1"))
  )
```

Comment: Nice use of `vapply`

Comment: @friede this approach is so much faster, too (see benchmarks in my answer) - base is best!